# Points for which $AX^2-BX^2$ is constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

My problem is from Israel Gelfand's Trigonometry textbook.

> *Page 9. Exercise 8:* Two points, A and B, are given in the plane. Describe the set of points for which $AX^2-BX^2$ is constant.

I would appreciate some hints on how to approach the problem.

Comment: I could think of a trivial case that might illuminate things. The difference works out as the constant zero when the two quantities are equal. This corresponds to when X is on the perpendicular bisector of AB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use coordinate geometry, letting the two points be $(p,0)$ and $(-p,0)$, and grind it out. Not much grinding! If you prefer (I don't) you can let the points be $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$.

Comment: Hey, first of all, thank you for the reply. Which two points are you talking about? A and B? where do I take the origin? I am sorry for stupid questions, I am trying to teach myself, I don't really have an instructor.

Comment: Because you will be more comfortable, I will use the ugly points. The square of the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(a_1,a_2)$ is $(x-a_1)^2 +(y-a_2)^2$. There is a similar expression for the square of the other distance. So our equation is $[(x-a_1)^2+(y-a_2)^2]-[(x-b_1)^2+(y-b_2)^2]=k$ (the constant). Expand the squares and subtract. The terms in $x^2$ and in $y^2$ cancel, and we get a linear equation, the equation of a **line**.

Comment: I got this equation as answer: $a_1^2-2a_1x-2a_2y+a_2^2+2b_1x+2b_2y-b_2^2+b_1^2=k$, so this line describes set of points where $AX^2-BX^2$ is constant right?

Comment: Yes. You might want to reorganize into the form $ax+by=c$. This is a bit ugly-looking. You might want to repeat with the choice of points I suggested. That will give you a nice simple equation (no $y$) and now you probably can use the information to give a more **geometric** argument.

Comment: Thank you very much André.

Comment: You are welcome. There is still some useful insight you can get, by looking at the geometry, not the algebra. The algebra is very powerful, but it does not give geometric insight into the question of "why is it a line?".

Comment: This particular book avoids algebra slogs so I suspect your answer, while valid, was not the approach Gelfand had in mind. The previous exercise in the book is about the set of points X such that AX^2 + BX^2 = AB^2, which is a circle with its center at the midpoint of A.B. Maybe that's a clue? The section is about the Pythagorean Theorem.